# socket always return -1

Tags: c, sockets

i am new in network programming , i wrote a simple code just to get a num of bytes in a captured packet ,but i cant start socket (always return -1 )here is the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/ioctl.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<net/if.h>
//#include<netinet/either.h>
#define ETHER_TYPE 0x0800

void main()
{
struct ifreq ifopts;
ssize_t numbytes=0;
int sockfd;
char ifname="eth0";
uint8_t buf[1024];

if((sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,0))<0)
{
printf("couldnt start socket \nsockfd = %d\n",sockfd);
exit(1);
}
strncpy(ifopts.ifr_name,ifname,sizeof(ifname)-1);
ioctl(sockfd,SIOCSIFFLAGS,&ifopts);
ifopts.ifr_flags |= IFF_PROMISC;
ioctl(sockfd,SIOCSIFFLAGS,&ifopts);
if((setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_BINDTODEVICE,ifname,sizeof(ifname)-1))<0)
printf("couldnt bind \n");
numbytes=recvfrom(sockfd,buf,1024,0,NULL,NULL);
printf("got packet with size %d",numbytes);
}
```

thanks

Comment: Perhaps you don't have enough permission to use `SOCK_RAW`.  What is `errno`?  It's a good idea to use `perror` when a system call fails.

Comment: SOCK_RAW requires root permissions. If all you want to do is send packets, use SOCK_STREAM (like TCP) or SOCK_DGRAM (like UDP).

Comment: Why not checking `errno` after getting `-1` from `socket`, so the reason would be more clear? (you can get error string by using `strerror(errno)`)

Comment: Couldn't find anything in the linux man pages, but on OS X (probably on BSD too): `SOCK_RAW sockets provide access to internal network protocols and interfaces.  The
     types SOCK_RAW, which is available only to the super-user`... And the error I got from `strerror(errno)` is `Operation not permitted`.

Comment: perhaps i should read more about perror
thanks a lot , i will try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to check `errno` to confirm this (it will be `EACCES`), but the failure is because your effective user doesn't have permission to use sockets of type `SOCK_RAW`.